# How to filter elements with regex expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to select all the a elements which point to external links, so I want a selector which picks only the href values matched with

```
/https?:\/\/[^\/\!\?\<\>\_\*\&\(\)\#\$\@]*/
```

that are different from

`window.location.hostname`

what's the correct expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be more robust solution, checking for different location hostname than main window:

```
var $externalLinks = $('a[href]').filter(function(){
    return this.hostname != window.location.hostname;
});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: @Vohuman Thx but not sure why this has been downvoted, i must be missing something obvious, maybe...?!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the answer. Sometimes the reason of downvote is not _technical_!

Comment: maybe the answer does not resolves around regex but it solves the problem i was going to use regex for

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a:not([href*="+window.location.hostname+"])[href*=http], a:not([href*="+window.location.hostname+"])[href*=https]")
```

Will give you all the links not having `window.location.hostname` but having `http` or `https`

Answer (score -2):

No regex needed.
Try this (using Jquery):

```
var links = $('a[href^="http"]');
```